# How to display the more then one value inside tooltip in bar chart.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js, tooltip, bar-chart

I am using [chart.js](https://www.chartjs.org/). I am sharing one example below. When I hover on the bar then I am getting tooltip with total votes.

Now my concern is, Is it possible to display more than one value inside the tooltip. As of now it is displaying **#of Votes 5.**

I have displayed the one more like `Amount 40`.

[image]

I tried below code but it's not working.

```
data: [[12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],[10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60]],
```

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
      //data: [[12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],[10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60]],
      backgroundColor: [
        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
      ],
      borderColor: [
        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
      ],
      borderWidth: 1
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.innerbox {
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="innerbox">
  <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="300"></canvas>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.8.0"></script>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the callback function `afterLabel` to display the second value like this:

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
      backgroundColor: [
        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
      ],
      borderColor: [
        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
      ],
      borderWidth: 1
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }]
    },
    tooltips: {
      callbacks: {
        afterLabel: function(tooltipItem, data) {
          var amount = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60];
          return "Amount " + amount[tooltipItem['index']];
        }
      }
    }

  }
});
```

```css
.innerbox {
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.8.0"></script>
<div class="innerbox">
  <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="300"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, It's working perfectly for me. Thanks for the help.